# R: Unable to view data when importing RData file

Tags: r, rdata

I am trying to import and view data in `.RData` file at my Windows 7 (x64) machine. I am using this command:

```
my_df <- load("~path_to_file/my_file.RData")
```

Data load seems to be fine. But:

```
head(my_df)
```

returns:

```
[1] "dfAllxY"
```

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `head(dfAllxY)`. The `load` command doesn't return an object, it returns the names of all the objects it loaded from the RData file since RData file may contain more than one object. Read the `?load` help page for more information.